# URL Rewrite NE|noescape

Tags: .htaccess, iis-7.5, url-rewrite-module

When i try to convert my htaccess file in IIS 7.5 i get an error about the NE flag not supported

for example

```
RewriteRule ^Nxt/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/nxt/$1 [NE,R=301,L]
```

Is there a way to rewrite this rule to make it work.

I have about 50 NE flags that i need to change but cannot figure out what will work.

I have tried removing the "NE" in the file and the rules will convert however they do not work.

I have tried removing the lines that "NE" completely same result.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [ISAPI's rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/docs/#RewriteRule), version 2 doesn't have the NE flag, or an equivalent. But it looks like [version 3 has the NE flag](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/doc/RewriteRule.htm) as well as a lot of the other ones from apache's mod_rewrite. You could try upgrading.

Comment: Either I am using it wrong or im not sure what im doing. The freeware version when I install it i run it it only give me options for my server level not site level. When i copy in my .htaccess file and read the output the NE flags are still set. This not helpful at all. Why cant i just simply convert it to something Microsoft can understand.